# Boundary layer and high order finite element methods

Tags: fluid-dynamics

When modeling boundary layers, it is typically required to have a highly refined mesh along the boundary. My question is if there has been success with high order finite element methods to overcome the need for highly refined meshes. Can a high order basis function of a finite element successfully capture the steep gradient in a boundary layer? Can anyone point me to examples? Thanks.

Comment: See [Laghos](https://github.com/CEED/Laghos) for an example.

Comment: If the solution is smooth, p-adaptivity comparing h-adaptivity will converge faster. And you can have anisotropic approx. order on hex or prism mesh, such that in normal and tangential direction is different.

Comment: Even with higher-order elements, we still need to use graded meshes for accurately modelling boundary layers. But, with higher-order elements, we don't need ridiculously fine meshes that are normally required in FVM.